# auto-folder documents with templates

Tags: ocr

I have about a million documents I need to move to new folders based on their content. I'm looking for a tool where I can give few samples and the program would find similar documents and move them to another folder.

I have different graphs and reports and pictures that have similar look within the group of documents but different values. It's easy to distinguish them by opening them manually, but it would take months to go through them all. Some sort of OCR maybe?

Comment: Can you define "similiar"? Similiar it what sense?

Comment: For example invoices "look similar", they have same design, logos, header, footer, but different customer details. Healthcare forms have also similar design and fields, but different patient details.

Comment: Are "similar" tied to templates? For instance if invoices are the same, are they all the same template and file type? Or are some .pdf and some .doc?

Comment: There might be for example 50k documents that come from Company A with one template, then 70k documents from Company B's template. I don't have access to the original template, just the .pdf/scanned .tiff.

Comment: The filenames don't suggest that they are similar?

Comment: Nope, it's not possible to figure out the document from the file name

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of OCR and ICR software with different functionality.
If you need only documents classification, you can try Recognition Server: http://www.abbyy.com/recognition_server/

Answer (score 0):

[ABBYY FlexiCapture](http://ABBYY%20FlexiCapture) does what you need.
This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gS9jI36BTIo) shows it.
I think it is expensive software, but for one million documents should be worth it.

On the paper, [IRISmart File](https://www.irislink.com/EN-US/c1605/IRISmart-File---Intelligent-naming---classification-software-.aspx) is an alternative that could also help sorting the documents and costs 199$. However, from the 10-days trial, I could not find how to do the OCR and rename the files. If someone knows, please comment.

It might also be worth looking at what OpenKM can do. Ther is  a community edition.

What you need belongs to the family of "Zonal OCR" also known as "Template-based OCR".